# Shortcode from ACF Default Value only working after post is saved

Tags: php, wordpress, advanced-custom-fields, shortcode

I have this shortcode which is saved in the Default Value text field of an ACF field. The field type is Wysiwig editor.

I get the Default Value text by using `acf_get_field('location_info')['default_value']` in my template file however the shortocde is only being processed after the post is opened and saved.

Before saving, the output is the shortcode itself.

So before saving: The quick brown [animal-name] jumps over...

And after saving the post: The quick brown fox jumps over...

The shortcode is generated through another plugin called 'Insert PHP Code Snippet'.

The problem: how to get WP to process the shortcode without having to save the post first?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the method within do_shortcode() function to process the shortcodes in the text before echo the text to screen.

```
<?php echo do_shortcode(acf_get_field('location_info')['default_value']) ?>
```